# Could not get unknown property 'VERSION_NAME' for project ':library' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I import the RippleBackground library for my project as a module, following exception was thrown

> Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'VERSION_NAME' for project ':library' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

But the versionName is already defined in the build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.skyfishjy.library"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionName "1.0.1"
        versionCode 2

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
}

apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

Anyone can explain where the error is?

Answer (score 2):

The publishing script imported on the last line requires some project properties, including `VERSION_NAME`, `GROUP` and others.

If you're not going to publish this library remove the line

```
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

Otherwise you'll need to put all the relevant properties in your `gradle.properties` file or provide them in the command line. You can open the URL in your browser and understand the properties from it.

Here, `VERSION_NAME` and `versionName` are not related.

**Note:** Android libraries don't have `applicationId`, `versionCode` or `versionName`. These properties are only used in Android apps. You can remove these lines.

Comment: Thanks. That helped me a lot